# How to get next page link in python beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have this link:

```
http://www.brothersoft.com/windows/categories.html
```

I am trying to to get the link for the item inside the div.
Example:

```
http://www.brothersoft.com/windows/mp3_audio/midi_tools/
```

I have tried this code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.brothersoft.com/windows/categories.html'

pageHtml = urllib.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(pageHtml)

sAll = [div.find('a') for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'brLeft'})]

for i in sAll:
    print "http://www.brothersoft.com"+i['href']
```

But I only get output:

```
http://www.brothersoft.com/windows/mp3_audio/
```

How can I get output that I needed?

Comment: Works perfect, what's the problem?

Comment: the output should be http://www.brothersoft.com/windows/mp3_audio/midi_tools/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Url `http://www.brothersoft.com/windows/mp3_audio/midi_tools/` is not in tag `<div class='brLeft'>`, so if output is `http://www.brothersoft.com/windows/mp3_audio/`, that's correct.

If you want to get the url you want, change

```
sAll = [div.find('a') for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'brLeft'})]
```

to

```
sAll = [div.find('a') for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'brRight'})]
```

**UPDATE:**

an example to get info inside 'midi_tools'

```
import urllib 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.brothersoft.com/windows/categories.html'
pageHtml = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageHtml)
sAll = [div.find('a') for div in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'brRight'})]
for i in sAll:
    suburl = "http://www.brothersoft.com"+i['href']    #which is a url like 'midi_tools'

    content = urllib.urlopen(suburl).read()
    anosoup = BeautifulSoup(content)
    ablock = anosoup.find('table',{'id':'courseTab'})
    for atr in ablock.findAll('tr',{'class':'border_bot '}):
        print atr.find('dt').a.string      #name
        print "http://www.brothersoft.com" + atr.find('a',{'class':'tabDownload'})['href']   #link
```

Comment: how if I want to get the the application name and links inside the midi_tools?

Comment: @wan mohd payed, that is similar to what you have done, get the content of midi_tools page, and find out which tag the information is in, then use `BeautifulSoup` to get the infomation.

Comment: @Davd.Zheng Do i need to use 'join' or something?

Comment: @wan mohd payed, sorry, I can't understand what do you mean by using 'join'? For what purpose?

Comment: Sorry, I actually have no idea how to code it. But how can i get the download link inside the midi_tools and print some string information about the software inside the midi_tools